# Remove duplicate rows in MS Access database file in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I want an easy way to remove duplicate rows in an MS Access database file.

Example:

```
[realtimedata]
 SecName | SecSym | Number
---------+--------+--------
 Mike    | 123    | 245
 Mike    | 123    | 245
```

Comment: This would heavily depend on what you consider "duplication" -- can you show an example of duplicate data items?

Comment: is it dublicate rows ?? or something else '

Comment: Can you give an example of how your tables/data currently looks, and show which rows you want to delete?

Comment: i have edited my question please check it

Comment: in my screenshot the rows and columns are same like Mike - Mike, 123-123,245-245 there are two records i want to delete 1 record in one of the two

Comment: Is there a Unique column on each row?

Comment: maybe this would help http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3077791/Delete-Duplicate-Records-From-Access-Tables.htm]

Answer (score 0):

1) Open a DataTable or Recordset that selects the table's unique identifier column(s) plus the columns that you're using to identify duplicate rows; the select statement must include an order by clause sorting on the duplicate-identifying columns.  In your example: `ORDER BY SecName, SecSym, Number`

2) Loop through the records, reading the values for the columns that identify duplicate rows.

3) If there are any duplicate rows, they'll be adjacent to one another, because the results have been sorted by those columns.  Therefore, if any row has the same values as the previous row, it is a duplicate, and should be deleted.

pseudo code snippet:

```
string prevSecName = null;
int prevSecSym = 0;
int prevNumber = 0;

const int idIndex = 0;
const int nameIndex = 1;
const int symIndex = 2;
const int numberIndex = 3;

var idsToDelete = new List<SomeType>();

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    if (prevSecName != null && prevSecName = row[nameIndex] && prevSecSym = row[symIndex] && prevNumber = row[numberIndex])
        idsToDelete.Add(row[idIndex]);
    prevSecName = row[nameIndex];
    prevSecSym = row[symIndex];
    prevNumber = row[numberIndex];
}
```